# I have installed TOR and I'cant run it

Tags: mac

this is the content of the historial connections.

```
27/5/17 12:01:52.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/5/17 12:01:52.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/5/17 12:01:53.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
27/5/17 12:01:53.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
27/5/17 12:01:54.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:01:55.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
27/5/17 12:01:56.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
27/5/17 12:01:56.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:01:56.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop3' (fresh): $8DFCD8FB3285E855F5A55EDDA35696C743ABFC4E~ndnop3 at 109.105.109.165 
27/5/17 12:01:56.300 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:56.300 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NX01' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (85.17.30.79:443) based on the configured
```

I' can't run tor after installed. It's strange because I never have been problems with TOR in MAC osx. My MAC OS X version is 10.11.6

This are the message in the clipboard

Bridge address.

```
27/5/17 12:01:56.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'NX01' (fresh): $FC259A04A328A07FED1413E9FC6526530D9FD87A~NX01 at 85.17.30.79 
27/5/17 12:01:56.300 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:56.400 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop5' (fresh): $BBB28DF0F201E706BE564EFE690FE9577DD8386D~ndnop5 at 109.105.109.147 
27/5/17 12:01:56.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:56.600 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'noether' (fresh): $7B126FAB960E5AC6A629C729434FF84FB5074EC2~noether at 192.99.11.54 
27/5/17 12:01:56.600 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:57.400 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'GreenBelt' (fresh): $C73ADBAC8ADFDBF0FC0F3F4E8091C0107D093716~GreenBelt at 154.35.22.9 
27/5/17 12:01:57.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:57.500 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Azadi' (fresh): $FE7840FE1E21FE0A0639ED176EDA00A3ECA1E34D~Azadi at 154.35.22.13 
27/5/17 12:01:57.500 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:57.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:01:57.700 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Lisbeth' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (192.95.36.142:443) based on the configured Bridge address. 
27/5/17 12:01:57.700 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Lisbeth' (fresh): $CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2~Lisbeth at 192.95.36.142 
27/5/17 12:01:57.700 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:58.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:01:58.400 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'MaBishomarim' (fresh): $A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637~MaBishomarim at 154.35.22.11 
27/5/17 12:01:58.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:58.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
27/5/17 12:01:58.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:01:59.200 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'cymrubridge33' (fresh): $0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955~cymrubridge33 at 38.229.33.83 
27/5/17 12:01:59.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:01:59.200 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'cymrubridge31' (fresh): $C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4~cymrubridge31 at 38.229.1.78 
27/5/17 12:01:59.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
27/5/17 12:02:01.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors 
27/5/17 12:02:01.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 5970/7148, and can only build 59% of likely paths. (We have 86% of guards bw, 84% of midpoint bw, and 82% of exit bw = 59% of path bw.) 
27/5/17 12:02:02.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 78%: Loading relay descriptors 
27/5/17 12:02:02.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
27/5/17 12:02:03.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
27/5/17 12:02:04.900 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
27/5/17 12:02:04.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
27/5/17 12:02:06.700 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
27/5/17 12:02:06.800 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
27/5/17 12:03:10.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:15937 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:03:10.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:4304 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:04:27.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:4304 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:04:27.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:15937 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '154.35.22.13:16815' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '83.212.101.3:50002' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '154.35.22.10:15937' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '154.35.22.11:16488' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '154.35.22.12:4304' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '154.35.22.9:12166' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '109.105.109.165:10527' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [NOTICE] Bridge at '109.105.109.147:13764' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for MaBishomarim 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for Mosaddegh 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for Azadi 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $FE7840FE1E21FE0A0639ED176EDA00A3ECA1E34D. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for Mosaddegh 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for MaBishomarim 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for JonbesheSabz 
27/5/17 12:11:37.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:38.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:11:40.100 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NX01' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (85.17.30.79:443) based on the configured Bridge address. 
27/5/17 12:11:40.100 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'NX01' (fresh): $FC259A04A328A07FED1413E9FC6526530D9FD87A~NX01 at 85.17.30.79 
27/5/17 12:11:40.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:11:40.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for MaBishomarim 
27/5/17 12:11:40.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $A832D176ECD5C7C6B58825AE22FC4C90FA249637. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:40.500 [WARN] Could not choose valid address for Mosaddegh 
27/5/17 12:11:40.500 [WARN] Could not make a one-hop connection to $8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55. Discarding this circuit. 
27/5/17 12:11:41.000 [NOTICE] Tried to fetch a descriptor directly from a bridge, but that bridge is not reachable through our firewall. 
27/5/17 12:11:41.500 [NOTICE] Tried to fetch a descriptor directly from a bridge, but that bridge is not reachable through our firewall. 
27/5/17 12:11:41.600 [NOTICE] Tried to fetch a descriptor directly from a bridge, but that bridge is not reachable through our firewall. 
27/5/17 12:11:41.700 [NOTICE] Tried to fetch a descriptor directly from a bridge, but that bridge is not reachable through our firewall. 
27/5/17 12:11:42.100 [NOTICE] Tried to fetch a descriptor directly from a bridge, but that bridge is not reachable through our firewall. 
27/5/17 12:12:25.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
27/5/17 12:14:34.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:14:34.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:14:35.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:14:35.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:15:49.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:16488 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:15:49.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:15937 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
27/5/17 12:15:49.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:4304 ("general SOCKS server failure")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like none of the default bridges are reachable by your `ReachableAddresses` policy. You've told Tor you can only access specific IP addresses or ports but none of the bridges have addresses that are compatible with that policy.

```
[NOTICE] Bridge at '109.105.109.147:13764' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
```

If you go: to Onion Menu -> Edit the settings for "Allowed Ports", then try to connect again you should be able to resolve this.

If your allowed ports is accurate and you aren't able to connect to any of the default bridges then you could try fetching some fresh bridges from [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/).

Comment: it's 90% the reason you've mentioned, in the rest 10% there's a DPI firewall elaborated